# How To Update total supply ERC20

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, ico

I have an ERC20 smart contract address
The total supply is 1,000,000,000,000
Now I want to increase the total supply
please help me
What code should I use in
https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 1):

The ERC20 token standard does not include update method (minting) for `totalSupply` unless you have built it before deploying. If you didn't do that and your contract is already deployed you have no other choice, but redeploying your contract.

Comment: hi Here's the code I used to build Token

https://etherscan.io/address/0xe5fe68179c71d9fb4c1fed2035f4bbff9dc7b967#code

Comment: You cannot update the ```totalSupply``` for this smart contract. The ```totalSupply``` will always stay ```10000000000000000000000000000```. Learn more about token mint.